# firefox - allow site to read cookies but not set them

Tags: firefox, cookies

I disallow cookies by default. There's an obnoxious site I've encountered that redirects to a **"To use this website, cookies must be enabled in your browser"** page. I've figured out the fields that need to be set and luckily it's not the ones that store the tracking information.

I used the storage inspector to enter these fields and the values and set the expiration date to 20 years from now. However, I still want to block the tracking information the website tries to set, so I don't want it to be able to set any cookies. I tried the `Block this website from setting cookies` option, however, I figured out that it also prevents the website from *reading* currently set cookies.

Is there a setting or extension that allows me to accomplish this? An extension that allows me to send specific headers to specific sites would also suffice provided it can set the `Cookie` header.

Comment: Wild guess... lock the file?

Comment: @Tetsujin Unfortunately the cookies are all stored in a single file, and I have sites I want to be able to set cookies.